# Reading file into object array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have to read from a data file which is formatted like this

abcd(string)  1(int)   2(int)   3(int)
abcde(string)    4(int)  3(int)   2(int)
.
.
.

I want to perform some functions which use the variables in the same line only. But here's my code. I'm a beginner so please correct me thank you.

in the .h file

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;


#ifndef CALC_H  
#define CALC_H


class Calc  
{  
public:

    void readFile(string file);

private:

    string name;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

#endif
```

in the implementation file

```
 #include "Vehicle.h"  
 #include iostream>  
 #include fstream>  
 #include string>  
 #include cstdlib>  
 #include cmath>  

 using namespace std;


void Vehicle::readFile(string filename)  
{  
   ifstream myIn;  

 int totalNum=0;  

myIn.open(filename.c_str());
if (!myIn)
{
    cerr<<"Data file failed to open!\n";
    exit (0);
}   
for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
{
    while (myIn.peek() != EOF)
    {
        myIn>>calc[i].name;
        myIn>>calc[i].a;
        myIn>>calc[i].b;
        myIn>>calc[i].c;

        totalNum++;
    }
}
myIN.close();
```

and then I want to display what i just read from the file

```
 for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)  
 cout << calc[i].name << calc[i].a << calc[i].b << calc[i].c << endl;
```

sorry I left out alot of stuff I just want to know if I on the right path. Thanks

Comment: Might as well use `while (myIn >> calc[i].name >> calc[i].a >> calc[i].b >> calc[i].c) {totalNum++;}`

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is to overload the `>>` operator for your class `Calc`.

```
class Calc {
   public:
      friend istream& operator >>(istream& myIn, Calc& calc);
};

istream& operator >>(istream& myIn, Calc& calc) {
    myIn >> calc.name;
    myIn >> calc.a;
    myIn >> calc.b;
    myIn >> calc.c;

    return myIn;     
}
```

Now you can just do:

```
while (myIn >> calc[i]) {
    ++totalNum;
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm this is a little dangerous, since it could fail mid stream, but I don't know whether that is acceptable and/or how to improve it.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Obviously OP would have to account for that...this was just a basic I/O tip.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I can't even vote yet. but does this work with object array? can I just add a loop and read from the first line like calc[i].name then calc[i].a?

Comment: @JasonLee this will read an entire Calc object and abstract/hide how it does it so you don't have to worry about re-coding it everytime you want to use it. In the while loop I posted above, this will read into an array of Calc objects. Be careful you're always reading in-bounds, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider designing it a bit differently.

create a class that holds one line i.e. string int int int - like you have it in "Calc" but without making it dependent on how you create a line (readfile). Lets call it "Line"

```
class Line
{
public:
  std::string name;
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;  
};
```

Now since you need to read several lines you will need some kind of container to hold them, create a vector of Line (or some other container)

```
std::vector<Line> contents;
```

then override the stream operator as Tushar suggested so when you read from a file (or from e.g. stdin) you can create instances of Line for each line you read, these instances you use to fill the 'contents' array

now you can start doing whatever it is you want to do with the lines i.e. the actual operation `calc`

Comment: Or can I create a loop in the client main.cc and just read one line and perform some functions and then repeat? how would you go about that?

Comment: there are many ways to handle this, you can do as you say as well without storing anything and just calculating as you read in.